# Replace null values in a column with previous updated value in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have the following dataframe:

| Id | Date | Int_type | Interest_rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 03/22/2023 | Floating | 0.044 |
| A | 03/22/2023 | Floating | 0.045 |
| A | 03/22/2023 | Floating | 0.046 |
| A | 03/24/2023 | Floating | 0.046 |
| A | 03/24/2023 | Fixed | Null |
| A | 03/24/2023 | Fixed | Null |
| A | 03/24/2023 | Missing | Null |
| A | 03/24/2023 | Missing | Null |
| A | 03/24/2023 | Fixed | Null |
| A | 03/24/2023 | Fixed | Null |
| A | 03/24/2023 | Fixed | Null |
| A | 03/24/2023 | Fixed | Null |
| A | 03/24/2023 | Fixed | Null |

This is what we need :
If interest rate is missing, and it is available in the previous row (for the same id and date combination)  and `int_type` is "FIXED", the interest rate from the previous period is rolled forward. Whenever the `int_type` is missing, interest rate is also null for those entries by default and we need to leave it as it is.

I have tried the following query:

```py
wind1=Window.partitionBy('id','date').orderBy('date')

df = df.withColumn('lag_int_rt',when((upper(col('Int_Type'))=='FIXED') & (col('Interest_rate').isNulI()),lag('Interest_rate').over(wind1)))

df = df.withColumn('lag_int_rt',when((upper(col('Int_Type'))=='FIXED') & (col('lag_int_rt').isNull()) & (upper(lag('Int_Type'). over(wind1)) !='MISSING') ,\
last('lag_int_rt',True).over(wind1)).otherwise(col('lag_int_rt')))

df = df.withColumn('final_interest',coalesce('Interest_rate','lag_int_rt'))
```

This is the output I am getting:

| Id | Date | Int_type | Interest_rate | Final_interest |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 03/22/2023 | Floating | 0.044 | 0.044 |
| A | 03/22/2023 | Floating | 0.045 | 0.045 |
| A | 03/22/2023 | Floating | 0.046 | 0.046 |
| A | 03/24/2023 | Floating | 0.046 | 0.046 |
| A | 03/24/2023 | Fixed | Null | 0.046 |
| A | 03/24/2023 | Fixed | Null | 0.046 |
| A | 03/24/2023 | Missing | Null | Null |
| A | 03/24/2023 | Missing | Null | Null |
| A | 03/24/2023 | Fixed | Null | Null |
| A | 03/24/2023 | Fixed | Null | 0.046 |
| A | 03/24/2023 | Fixed | Null | 0.046 |
| A | 03/24/2023 | Fixed | Null | 0.046 |
| A | 03/24/2023 | Fixed | Null | 0.046 |

But this is the output I expect:

| Id | Date | Int_type | Interest_rate | Final_interest |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 03/22/2023 | Floating | 0.044 | 0.044 |
| A | 03/22/2023 | Floating | 0.045 | 0.045 |
| A | 03/22/2023 | Floating | 0.046 | 0.046 |
| A | 03/24/2023 | Floating | 0.046 | 0.046 |
| A | 03/24/2023 | Fixed | Null | 0.046 |
| A | 03/24/2023 | Fixed | Null | 0.046 |
| A | 03/24/2023 | Missing | Null | Null |
| A | 03/24/2023 | Missing | Null | Null |
| A | 03/24/2023 | Fixed | Null | Null |
| A | 03/24/2023 | Fixed | Null | Null |
| A | 03/24/2023 | Fixed | Null | Null |
| A | 03/24/2023 | Fixed | Null | Null |
| A | 03/24/2023 | Fixed | Null | Null |

For the last 5 rows where `int_type` is fixed, but the previous row has missing interest rate, so we need to roll forward the missing interest rate. My code is working for just the first row with `int_type=Fixed` but not for consecutive rows, as the previous row value is not getting updated in the same step.

Comment: do you have a column that has the dataframe order? perhaps a field with time? your current dataframe's row order within dates will not be maintained in distributed processing.

Comment: If the dataframe is sorted by all variables( some of them have not been shown here to avoid unnecessary information) and then we create a ‘row_number()’ field over the above created window ,then the current distribution will be maintained and rows will be ordered accordingly as shown here